# No multiplayer option for G-Force on PS2?

Tags: ps2, g-force

The specs for the game G-Force on Playstation 2 say "1 or 2 players."

However, when playing the game, we cannot figure out how to enable two-player mode. There does not seem to be a multiplayer option in any of the menus...

Both controllers are plugged in, but we only have one memory card. Could that have anything to do with it?

Both controllers work, and multiplayer does work in other games.
The console is a PS2 slim.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

After taking another look at, it's only the dutch version that says 1 or 2 players... In French it says 1 player.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Steamcommunity](https://steamcommunity.com/app/319170/discussions/0/613937943142042920/):

> There isn't local coop or multiplayer. All the Disney games say they have it when they don't.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that only appied to the windows version. p.s. tried to +1, but insufficient rep.

Comment: @BerrievanLunteren glad to help. Don't worry, you can still accept answers by the green tick.